# Saving or passing results of SQL query to another table on another server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to save the results of a query (table) to SQL database which is on different server?

I have the following problem. I have only READ access to a HugeDatabase. I can execute Select commend an then I want to JOIN the results with another table 'TableB' which is on my local server. I cannot create views on HugeDatabase server (no rights, READ ONLY). I cannot make a linked server on HugeDatabes server to my local server (admin of the server does not allow that). Note that I have only sufficient permission to change settings of my local SQL server. Dropping the HugeDatabase to my local server is pointless since it is huge and my query takes only seconds.

Of course I can save the results as CSV and import it to a table on my local server. But this is Middle Ages way. I am in a need to execute the query every 5 minutes and make a JOIN with results, so dropping results to CSV is a fatal solution. Can you please suggest me a better way?

Comment: CSV sounds like your best option, to be honest. BCP is surprisingly quick and surprisingly powerful. Why do you need to run it every 5 minutes, exactly?

Comment: I don't think this will be possible using pure SQL. Why not use a Php script to do your work for you?

Comment: create a linked server in your local sql server which is connects to the hugeDB server

Comment: @gvee How to use BCP? I need it every 5 min only in 2 critical hours in month. I have to see which tasks have been done and the task are measured in value terms (not Yes or No). The values have to update.

Comment: @FarhangAmary but I want to avoid importing Huge db and then querying it. I want to use just the results which I have at instant after my query.

Comment: by creating the linked server you are not importing data, it is just a link to your server and you will get only the result of your query

Comment: If I query 1 million rows on Huge db which is pipelined to my local as a linked server, are you sure that the query is sent to server, and only let's say 8 rows of report is sent back to my local server? Or 1 million rows is first sent to my local, and then queried to 8 rows?